# Linux- How to set default values for future new users and create an empty file that is copied to each new users home directory?

Tags: linux, permissions, useradd

In Linux on my Virtual Box, How do I set default values for any future new user? Also, how do I create an empty file named TESTFILE and have it copied to each new users home directory.

I believe I did the second question correctly. Are the steps below correct for question 2?

```
root# touch testfile.txt
root# cp -a ~/testfile.txt /etc/skel/
```

Then to ensure it worked I created a new user and listed files in that directory:

```
root# useradd -c "NewUser" -md /home/NU -e MONTH/DATE/YEAR -s /bin/bash -u 2000 newuser
root# su - newuser
newuser~ ls -l

OUTPUT --> total 0
-rw-r--r-r-- newuser DATE testfile.txt
```

THANK YOU FOR ALL HELP! I AM NEW AT LINUX.

Comment: Obviously the file you put into /etc/skel is not called `FAKE`. What default values are you thinking of?

Comment: You don't need to  create the file in root's home dir and then copy it to /etc/skel (although that obviously works).  You can create it in /etc/skel, with no need to copy it: `touch /etc/skel/testfile.txt` (as root, of course, because only root has permission to write in /etc/skel).